# How to delete all website data from the system? (https://twitch.tv -site not working anymore)

Tags: firefox, chromium, websites

Twitch.tv website has always been kinda janky when I switched to Linux; usually it takes multiple tries before it loads everything instead of just showing that "error loading module"-ghost. But couple of days ago it stopped completely working. The site doesn't load at all, only showing a white screen with the logo on the left up corner and loading symbol in the middle.

I tried to delete all the data from Firefox couple of times, it didn't do anything. I also tried to delete the twitch folders from the Firefox's "storage" folder. But the thing is, this also happens on Chromium. So it's not Firefox-specific. All the other sites I use work completely normally. Also the app on my phone works normally.

I have no idea where in Ubuntu some sort of data is stored, that has now messed up the website completely. How can I delete all the data my PC has gathered from twitch.tv?

Comment: Also absolutely relevant: what browser extensions do you use? E.g. various adblockers are on the list of highly likely candidates for this kind of a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm putting the solution here in case someone else has this problem. It was pretty straight-forward: **I restarted my router**. And if that doesn't work for someone else, maybe resetting the whole thing does.

Answer (score 1):

You do not explained which version of Firefox you use.

For Firefox 93.0 look at Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Cookies and Site Data -> Manage Data -> Remove Selected

Comment: Thank you for replying! I'm indeed using the 93.0 version. I didn't know you can erase Site Data from there too so I appreciate this piece of information.